# Why include UniSwapRouterV2 in Erc20 Contract?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, uniswap

Many ERC20 coins like SafeMoon include `UniSwapRouterV2` in their contract. What are the benefits of this? Is it ok not to include a router?

e.g. SafeMoon's Router code:

```
interface IUniswapV2Router01 {
function factory() external pure returns (address);
function WETH() external pure returns (address);

function addLiquidity(
    address tokenA,
    address tokenB,
    uint amountADesired,
    uint amountBDesired,
    uint amountAMin,
    uint amountBMin,
    address to,
    uint deadline
) external returns (uint amountA, uint amountB, uint liquidity);
function addLiquidityETH(
    address token,
    uint amountTokenDesired,
    uint amountTokenMin,
    uint amountETHMin,
    address to,
    uint deadline
) external payable returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH, uint liquidity);
function removeLiquidity(
    address tokenA,
    address tokenB,
    uint liquidity,
    uint amountAMin,
    uint amountBMin,
    address to,
    uint deadline
) external returns (uint amountA, uint amountB);
function removeLiquidityETH(
    address token,
    uint liquidity,
    uint amountTokenMin,
    uint amountETHMin,
    address to,
    uint deadline
) external returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH);
function removeLiquidityWithPermit(
    address tokenA,
    address tokenB,
    uint liquidity,
    uint amountAMin,
    uint amountBMin,
    address to,
    uint deadline,
    bool approveMax, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s
) external returns (uint amountA, uint amountB);
function removeLiquidityETHWithPermit(
    address token,
    uint liquidity,
    uint amountTokenMin,
    uint amountETHMin,
    address to,
    uint deadline,
    bool approveMax, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s
) external returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH);
function swapExactTokensForTokens(
    uint amountIn,
    uint amountOutMin,
    address[] calldata path,
    address to,
    uint deadline
) external returns (uint[] memory amounts);
function swapTokensForExactTokens(
    uint amountOut,
    uint amountInMax,
    address[] calldata path,
    address to,
    uint deadline
) external returns (uint[] memory amounts);
function swapExactETHForTokens(uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
    external
    payable
    returns (uint[] memory amounts);
function swapTokensForExactETH(uint amountOut, uint amountInMax, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
    external
    returns (uint[] memory amounts);
function swapExactTokensForETH(uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
    external
    returns (uint[] memory amounts);
function swapETHForExactTokens(uint amountOut, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
    external
    payable
    returns (uint[] memory amounts);

function quote(uint amountA, uint reserveA, uint reserveB) external pure returns (uint amountB);
function getAmountOut(uint amountIn, uint reserveIn, uint reserveOut) external pure returns (uint amountOut);
function getAmountIn(uint amountOut, uint reserveIn, uint reserveOut) external pure returns (uint amountIn);
function getAmountsOut(uint amountIn, address[] calldata path) external view returns (uint[] memory amounts);
function getAmountsIn(uint amountOut, address[] calldata path) external view returns (uint[] memory amounts);
}



// pragma solidity >=0.6.2;

interface IUniswapV2Router02 is IUniswapV2Router01 {
function removeLiquidityETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
    address token,
    uint liquidity,
    uint amountTokenMin,
    uint amountETHMin,
    address to,
    uint deadline
) external returns (uint amountETH);
function removeLiquidityETHWithPermitSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
    address token,
    uint liquidity,
    uint amountTokenMin,
    uint amountETHMin,
    address to,
    uint deadline,
    bool approveMax, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s
) external returns (uint amountETH);

function swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
    uint amountIn,
    uint amountOutMin,
    address[] calldata path,
    address to,
    uint deadline
) external;
function swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
    uint amountOutMin,
    address[] calldata path,
    address to,
    uint deadline
) external payable;
function swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
    uint amountIn,
    uint amountOutMin,
    address[] calldata path,
    address to,
    uint deadline
) external;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is usually done to create a token pair in Uniswap.

It is needed for the token to allow the tokenPair some privileged actions like rebalancing liquidity for example.

Answer (score 1):

A little strange question.
Many ERC20 token contracts involve IUniswapV2Router01 and IUniswapV2Router02 interface.
They call functions of interface to interact with Uniswap DEX protocol.
Many tokens implement automatic liquidity acquisition as Safemoon does.
They do this by calling `addLiquidity` function of Uniswap Router Contract.
And also they can call swap functions such as `swapTokensForExactETH` or `swapTokensForExactTokens`.
Thus, they should include router interface in their smart contract.